# Suppose $f(x,y)$ satisfies $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\leq \phi (|y_1-y_2|)$ where $\phi (0)=0$ and $\phi^{\prime}(0)=0$. Prove $f$ does not depend on $y$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not even sure how to begin. I figure if $f$ doesn't depend on $y$ then $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|=0$ for all $y_0,y_1$, so I thought I might begin by showing that $\phi=0$ because then the result would follow. But there aren't enough hypotheses to show $\phi=0$.

EDIT: Based on a suggestion below to use MVT I have attempted a solution.

$|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\leq \phi (|y_1-y_2|) \implies \frac{|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|}{|y_2-y_1|}\leq \frac{\phi (|y_1-y_2|)}{|y_2-y_1|}$
then

$0\leq\lim_{y_2\rightarrow y_1}\frac{|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|}{|y_2-y_1|}\leq \lim_{y_2\rightarrow y_1}\frac{\phi (|y_1-y_2|)}{|y_2-y_1|}=0$

by continuity, (although I must admit I am not confident about this logic).

This implies $D_yf$ is identically $0$. Therefore, $f(x,y_1)=f(x,y_2)$

Comment: You also mean $\phi'(0)=0$?

Comment: Yes. I will edit that.

Comment: Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: And also $\phi(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your function is defined on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$, or at least on $I\times I$, where $I$ is an interval.

Fix $x$, and let $f_x(y)=f(x,y)$. Let $y_0\in\mathbb R$. Then, for $h\neq 0$, $$\left|\frac{f_x(y_0+h)-f_x(y_0)}{h}\right|\leq\frac{|\phi(h)|}{|h|}=\left|\frac{\phi(h)}{h}\right|.$$ As $h\to 0$, $\phi(h)/h\to 0$, therefore $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_x(y_0+h)-f_x(y_0)}{h}=0$$ for all $y_0$. Therefore $f_x'=0$, so $f_x$ is a constant, which shows that $f$ does not depends on $y$.